# Group by and calculation from value on the next row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm quite new to sql server. I can't seem to figure this out. I have a table that looks like this.

[image]

I need to be able to calculate the percentage change in the number for each name, for each year, in the column p. So the end result should look like this.

[image]

Comment: What RDBMS are you *really* using, MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products. Also your expected results don't make sense. 1000 + 50% is 1500, not 2000, however, if we reverse the logic (as 1000 *is* 50% of 2000) then 500 is **not** 600 - 20% (480 is).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to tell us which DBMS you use. (MySQL, SQL Server, postgreSQL, SQLite, Oracle, etc.) Also, please show us the definition of your table: the answer will be very different if you store those `Date` values in text strings than if you store them in `DATE` columns.

Comment: Your logic is inconsistent, 600 is 20% larger than 500 but 2000 is 100% larger than 1000. Please explain your criteria and provide proper table schema definitions

Comment: @Larnu Sorry, I made a miscalculation. I edited the question and I am using SQL server.

Comment: @O.Jones I am using SQL Server. The date is stored in date format, they are not text strings.

Comment: @sTTu Sorry, I made a miscalculation. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily calculate the % difference using lag()

```
select name, date, number, 
Cast(((number * 1.0) - Lag(number,1) over(partition by name order by date))/ Lag(number,1) over(partition by name order by date) * 100 as int)
from table
```